# error when formatting external disk

Tags: partitioning, usb, 17.10

I have a pendrive with the installer of ubuntu 16.04 which I want to format to give it another use but when I try to format it I get the following error:

[screenshot with error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MsgFW.png)

how to solve this error?

Translation of screenshot:

ERROR deleting partition
...
controler says physical block size is 2048 bytes, but Linux says that it is 512 bytes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use gparted to write a new partition table (msdos) 
Select Device -> Create Partition Table (msdos)

If gparted is not install run:
sudo apt-get install gparted

Comment: Thank for you help,  gpated worked correctly. I eliminate the partition without any problem